# Creating a drill-down form in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm trying to create a submission form in a web app using AngularJS, in which each form entry's options are dependent upon the response to a previous form entry. I'd like to keep it all on one page for simplicity, and further form items would either be greyed out before the previous form entry is filled or pop-in when the previous response is validated. I imagine this concept probably has a name, but I've struggled to find examples or tutorials for the idea by trying to get the right keywords for relevant search results. What is this concept called?

Here is a simplified example of the form, where a user submits a tournament result. A constant provider supplies the objects that define the drop-down options (e.g. `allSports.team=['Basketball', Soccer', ...]`), but which options are displayed depends on previous user input (e.g. `category=team`).

```
- What is the name of the tournament?
- What category of tournament sport is it? (drop down)
  - Team (yes)
  - Individual
- What sport is it? (drop down)
  - Basketball
  - Soccer (yes)
- How many games were played in the tournament? (text entry)
  - 3*
- For game 1, what was the name of the home team?
  - Cougars
- For game 1, what was the name of the away team?
  - Penguin
- Indicate which team won game 1:
  - Cougars (yes) 
  - Penguins
- (repeat for games 2-3)
```

The submission button would add a `tournament` object to a `tournaments` array of objects, similar to the following:

```
var tournaments = [
  { 'tourneyName' = 'Cougar Classic',
    'sportType' = 'Team',
    'sportName' = 'Soccer',
    'games' = [
      { 'teams' = [ 'Cougars', 'Penguins' ],
        'winner' = 'Cougars' },
      { 'teams' = [ 'Cougars', 'Penguins' ],
        'winner' = 'Penguins' },
      { 'teams' = [ 'Cougars', 'Penguins' ],
        'winner' = 'Cougars' }
      ]       
  },
  (next tournament)  
]
```

On the web app, the users could then search for tournaments by specific criteria (all basketball tournaments, soccer tournaments in which penguins win, all individual sports, etc.)

Any resources or help you could provide in helping me accomplish something like this would be appreciated. I'm pretty familiar with the basics of Angular and simple form submission, but I haven't really been able to find something of this scope in the tutorials I've done. Also, I'm working on this with angular-meteor, so if anyone with expertise there has any more specific recommendations (relevant packages, etc.), those would be very welcome.

Comment: Could you try to use getbootstrap for layout, and use angular-forms: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms.

Comment: I would recommend you take a look at the wealth of examples using angular-formly: http://angular-formly.com/ you could totally build this with angular-formly and you'll love it :-)

Comment: Great, it took me a bit to get it to work with Meteor correctly, but I'm giving angular-formly a shot. I've watched all the videos at it seems like it'll do the job nicely. I figured out how to set options for a `select` type from an array of name/type objects (scotch.io tutorial), but now I need to figure out how to create name/type objects for the options conditionally from another object. Also, is there a way to use it to create a variable number of fields? In the OP example, the user inputs 3 games were played: how do you make formly generate X sets of the game-specific questions?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it way at the bottom! :) http://angular-formly.com/#/example/advanced/repeating-section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the name of the concept I was looking for is called "Cascading Selects." Once I figured that out, I was able to find a number of helpful resources to accomplish this. [Here is one example](http://www.codescratcher.com/angularjs/cascading-dropdownlist-in-angularjs/). Funny how important knowing the right vocabulary can be!

I found that [angular-formly](http://angular-formly.com/#/) accomplishes a lot of the other things I was looking for, too, in that cascading can be integrated, options can be enabled/disabled interactively, and so much more.

I hope this finding helps someone else!